# Finding complements of direct summands

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $B=\mathbb Z⊕\mathbb Z_4$. How could we prove that $B_1=(1,\bar 1)\mathbb Z$ and $B_2=(1,\bar 2)\mathbb Z$ are direct summands in $B$?

Or, the same question for $A=\mathbb Z⊕\mathbb Z$ and $A_1=(1,0)\mathbb Z$ , $A_2=(1,2)\mathbb Z$?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: For the second question, it seems to me that $A_1$ is just isomorhic with $\mathbb Z$, so clearly it is a direct summand.

Comment: By that logic, $(2, 0)\cdot\mathbb{Z}$ is a direct summand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard" direct summands of $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$ are $(1,0)\mathbb Z$ and $(0,1)\mathbb Z$. (It's easy to check that $(1,0)\mathbb Z+(0,1)\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$ and $(1,0)\mathbb Z\cap (0,1)\mathbb Z=\{(0,0)\}$.) Note that if you make a $2\times 2$ matrix with the two vectors you get the identity matrix.

Use the above example as a pattern, and try to build a matrix whose first row is $(1\ 2)$ and has the [SNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) the identity matrix.

For the first question I can't see a pattern, but my tries show that a complement of $B_1$, respectively $B_2$ can be $(0,\bar 1)\mathbb Z$.

Comment: No need to check Smith Normal Form - just check determinant is $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: Determinants are much quicker to find...

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. In a word: automorphisms.